# Make HTTP Request with an absolute URL in the Request URL

Tags: http, go

I was wondering if it's possible to make a request as follows using Go's `net/http` library:

```
GET http://test2.com/thisisatest HTTP/1.1
Host: test1.com
```

To clarify, if I'm sending a request to localhost I don't want to change the host header as in:

```
nc -lnvp 8001
listening on [any] 8001 ...
connect to [127.0.0.1] from (UNKNOWN) [127.0.0.1] 55122
GET /headers HTTP/1.1
Host: not-localhost
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

But what I intend is to have the full URL in the request line:

```
nc -lnvp 8001
listening on [any] 8001 ...
connect to [127.0.0.1] from (UNKNOWN) [127.0.0.1] 55122
GET http://localhost/headers HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

I can't seem to find any information about it. If it's not possible using `net/http` is there any other way that this would be doable?

Thank you!

Diego

Comment: would a more appropriate title be, "Make HTTP Request with a Host header different from the Host in the Request URL" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this us undoable with net/http because net/http implements HTTP and what you want to do simply isn't HTTP.

> If it's not possible using net/http is there any other way that this would be doable?

Do raw networking, i.e. use package net.

This is wrong. Sorry.

Comment: I disagree with the assertion that setting a Host header that doesn't match the host of the URL "simply isn't HTTP".  I'm not even sure it's out of spec for it to not match URL https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html.

Comment: Hi @DanielFarrell, I think he was right and this might not be doable without using raw requests.

Answer (score 2):

From https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.Host,

```
// For client requests, Host optionally overrides the Host
// header to send. If empty, the Request.Write method uses
// the value of URL.Host. Host may contain an international
// domain name.
```

So you should be able to craft your request, set it's `Host` field to whatever you desire, and then make the request.

Consider the following code.  [It doesn't work on the Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/gxcHy42GiHl) (which won't allow external connections) but should work on your workstation.

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://httpbin.org/headers", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    req.Host = "myserver.com"
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", `application/json`)
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else if _, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, resp.Body); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

https://httpbin.org/headers returns the headers sent with a request, so it is a useful way to verify this works.  My results:

```
{
  "headers": {
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Host": "myserver.com",
    "User-Agent": "Go-http-client/2.0",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6217a78b-27317e7e06a097cb293b5db1"
  }
}
```

As you can see, since I set the request Host, the http library didn't set it from the URL.

In this case, httpbin request handler doesn't mind that the request header doesn't match the url.  Other sites might [return a 400 Bad Request](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) if the host header does not match.

Note that you cannot achieve the same by maniuplating a `Host` header directly.  You must use `Request.Host`.

Comment: Thank you for answering, unfortuantely this is not what I mean to do, I'll update the question.